# Fetch Api - Delete - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, cors, fetch-api, http-delete

I got many solution no one helped for me. i have followed all the solutions  set all required headers. still its showing the below error.

> Fetch API cannot load
>   http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/1. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7777' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

my fetch request :

```
fetch('http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/' +1, {
    method: "DELETE",       
    headers: {    
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' ,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'  : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'DELETE',
     'mode'  : 'cors' 

    }, 

    })
    .then(function(resp){

    })
```

I tried set mode : no-cors also.

My web api code :

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    { 
        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteEmployee(int id)
        {
            using (var ctx = new Employee())
            {
                var existingemp = ctx.tempemp.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                ctx.Entry(existingemp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I have set CORS in WebApiConfig.cs also

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a normal request to `http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/` via the browser ... maybe firefox , and once you get a response, 

Open dev console network panel, do `edit and resend` 

Add `Origin:http://localhost` and post the new response headers here?

Also, you **Should Not** add any `access-control` headers in the fetch request. These headers are supposed to be response headers

Comment: This happens **when appropriate response headers** are **Not** found by fetch. Looking at your response headers is the only way you can troubleshoot it. **Opaque** responses IMO won't give you anything to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate Access Control Headers **Absolutely Need** to be set via

`http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/`, to enable `http://localhost:7777` make a permitted delete

- Check on a browser's Network Panel, by doing a normal request
- Open up the network request in question - Do `edit and resend`(assuming firefox)
- Add request header `Origin:http://localhost` and resend the request

Post the response headers.

Further,

- Choose a different User to delete when you resend the requests, or may be a different method than a `delete` for troubleshooting before a solution

**Note** Make sure you are requesting for something that doesn't give you a `404`

When you look at the **response** headers , If you Do not see `Access-control-allow-origin` allowing localhost:7777, Or,

`Access-control-allow-methods` allowing delete, your request is *bound* to fail.

In which case, maybe you have not configured your API at port 25424 correctly yet, to send these responses

Answer (score -1):

I got solution myself after 2 hours.
The issue is i forgot to put 'id?=' in my request.

```
fetch('http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/' +1,
```

Instead of this . I Used below to solve ths issue.

```
fetch('http://localhost:25424/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee?id=' +1,
```